# Vscode SSH Jump Failed with macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, ssh

I can connect to the first server with key but cannot connet to the second server jumping with the first server. I doubt it is a bug on MacOS because I can jump to the seceond server with command line. Is there ANYONE knows what happened here?
Here is the config:

```html
Host comp
  HostName xx.xx.xxx.xxx
  User xxxx
  Port 22
  IdentityFile ***************

Host local
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  Port ****
  User xxxx
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -x -W %h:%p comp
  IdentityFile ***************
```

Here is the error information:

```html
[19:55:48.660] Log Level: 2
[19:55:48.662] remote-ssh@0.55.0
[19:55:48.662] darwin x64
[19:55:48.663] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+localhost", attempt 1
[19:55:48.663] SSH Resolver called for host: localhost
[19:55:48.663] Setting up SSH remote "localhost"
[19:55:48.669] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/5q/****************_tr0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-localhost-install.lock
[19:55:48.713] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/gy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-localhost-************************************-0.55.0/data.json
[19:55:48.742] Using commit id "***********************************" and quality "stable" for server
[19:55:48.743] Install and start server if needed
[19:55:48.779] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[19:55:48.854] > OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

[19:55:48.860] Using SSH config file "/Users/gy/.ssh/config/vscodeconfig"
[19:55:48.861] askpass server listening on /var/folders/5q/******************_tr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-**********************************.sock
[19:55:48.862] Spawning local server with {"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/5q/**************_tr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-********************************.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","54815","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","-F","/Users/gy/.ssh/config/vscodeconfig","localhost"],"dataFilePath":"/Users/gy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-localhost-*********************************-0.55.0/data.json"}
[19:55:48.862] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Renderer)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/5q/********************_tr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-**********************************.sock"}
[19:55:48.871] Spawned 34492
[19:55:48.987] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 34493
[19:55:49.008] stderr> OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
[19:55:50.129] stderr> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
[19:55:50.131] > local-server> ssh child died, shutting down
[19:55:50.136] Local server exit: 0
[19:55:50.136] Received install output: OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

[19:55:50.137] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
[19:55:50.137] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[19:55:50.141] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:1:130564)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:1:127671)
    at Object.t.tryInstallWithLocalServer (/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:102339)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async /Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:104310
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:109845)
    at async /Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:100912
    at async R (/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:97702)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:100561)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:107840)
    at async /Users/gy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/extension.js:127:141955
[19:55:50.143] ------
```

Could someone enlighten me on the reason for the problem or on a possible solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem.
Later it disappears after I turn off the agent server.
Maybe you can try this.